# SharePoint use of windows identity and connection pooling

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, connection-pooling, wss-3.0

When a user accesses a SharePoint site he is identified by his wndows identity.

I was wondering which identity is used to access the database. Is it the identity of the user or does it use the windows identity of a service, or order to gain the benefits of connection pooling.

Thanks

Shiraz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually the account set in the app pool of your share point site. To find out go to IIS, properties of the sharepoint site -> home tab -> Application pool (note the app pool). Go to that app pool -> right click properties -> Identity. That is the account used to access the database.

Hope this helps.